# Round time to nearest 10 milliseconds

Tags: excel

I have some time data that, without VBA, I need to round to the nearest 10 milliseconds.  For example:

```
input: 01:02:03.017 output:  01:02:03.020
input: 03:12:44.123 output:  03:12:44.120
```

Current approach is to convert to an integer number of milliseconds; round that to the nearest 10; finally convert back to time:

```
=ROUND(A1*86400000,10)/86400000
```

I must be making a really stupid error, just don't see it.

**EDIT:**

The formula is returning the same value as the input?!?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @PeterT  No error, the output is like the input..........its like *ROUND()* is not doing anything!

Comment: I'm thinking the granularity of the value in A1 is also 10 msecs.  (I used `=NOW()` in A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `10` to `0`

By multiplying the value you want the round to the nearest integer, then divide again.  By using 10 you are rounding to the 10th decimal place after creating a integer time.

```
=ROUND(A1*86400000,0)/86400000
```

[image]

Comment: My calculation shows there are 86,400,000 msecs in a day. But you're dropping one order of magnitude because... 1,000 msecs is one second. So the divisor should be 8,640,000 secs per day. That way you get the decimal seconds. Doh!

Comment: Thanks Scott...............I am bug-blind to my own bugs..........I miss-used the *ROUND()* function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your time data is in column A:

```
=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss.00")+0
```

[image]

Change the number format with `TEXT`, then add the ending 0 with `+0`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Elegant solution, although I think it could be fine-tuned. In the formula the 0 could be added with `&"0"` (instead of `+0`). And you can also wrap this with `TIMEVALUE` to convert again in a valid Excel timestamp. So the formula would become `=TIMEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss.00")&"0")`

Comment: @PeterK.Great ideas!  Strongly suggest you add an additional Answer to capture the idea.